# Basic Auth on bluemix

Tags: cloud, websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud

I am trying to deploy a web application on BlueMix Liberty Profile and I want to enable Basic HTTP authentication on this application.

The app seems to be running fine, but no web.xml changes or updates allow me to do basic or form based auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For details on enabling security on liberty refer to Liberty guide - in short you would need to edit your web.xml and add the required security constraints.

Example:

```
<security-role>
  <role-name>restricted</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Web Application</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>restricted</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Restricted area</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Once you have that done, you would need to setup basic auth registry and role mapping in Liberty - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.express.doc/ae/twlp_sec_basicreg_full.html?cp=SS7JFU_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-4-0-1

And finally, you would need to redeploy your app with the complete liberty server, see https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#optionsforpushinglibertyapplications "Pushing Liberty Server" for this.